# Hacer un metodo de validacion generico en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy intentando mejorar un poco mi codigo y puesto que tengo que hacer una validacion en varios metodos de varios controladores, me gustaria hacer un metodo generico en el Controlador Controller, y redireccionar las validaciones alli.
He probado varias opciones pero no consigo hacerlas funcionar, no se muy bien por que

En el Controlador "CONTROLLER"

```
protected function validattion($request,$reglas,$mensajes = null)
{

    $validador = \Validator($request,$reglas,$mensajes = []);

    if ($validador->fails()) :
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validador);
     endif;

}
```

y luego desde cualquier otro metodo de cualquier otro controlador lo llamo asi

```
 public function crearEstudiantes(Request $request)
    {
        $reglas = 
          [
            'nombre' => 'min:2',
            'direccion' => 'min:2',
            'telefono' => 'min:2'
          ];

        $this->validattion($request->all(),$reglas);

         ////////////////////////
         CODIGO PARA CREAR ESTUDIANTE


    }
```

Si copio tal cual el contenido del  metodo validattion(ubicado en el Controlador CONTROLER)  en crearEstudiantes(u otro metodo) de este modo

```
/////////////////////////EDICION DE LA PREGUNTA 1///////////////////////////
     public function crearEstudiantes(Request $request)
        {
            $reglas = 
              [
                'nombre' => 'min:2',
                'direccion' => 'min:2',
                'telefono' => 'min:2'
              ];

               $validador = \Validator::make($request->all(),$reglas);

             if ($validador->fails()) :
                 return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validador);
              endif;
        }


/////////////////////FIN DE EDICION DE LA PREGUNTA 1/////////////////////////
```

funciona perfecto, es decir valida, pero al hacer la llamada al metodo validattion dentro de crearEstudiante no da error pero simplemente no hace nada y sigue ejecutando el codigo que haya en ese metodo.
¿Como podria resolver esto.?

Comment: Puede parecer innecesario, pero ¿puedes agregar el código que sí funciona? Tengo una sospecha y me gustaría confirmarla pero quisiera ver el método `crearEstudiantes()` con el código que sí funciona.

Comment: He añadido una edicion al tema principal, donde añado el codigo que me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema parece ser que no estás utilizando un return en el método que llama la validación, tampoco estás lanzando la excepción de validación, todo esto cuando ocurra un error y esta falle.

Según la documentación de Laravel tienes dos opciones, aunque en la práctica tienes más:

1. Utilizar el trait `ValidatesRequests` en el controlador base y así utilizar su método `validate()` que lanza la excepción de validación respectiva:

   ```
   // ...
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

   abstract class Controller extends BaseController
   {
        // ...
        use ValidatesRequests;

        public funcion crearEstudiantes(Request $request)
        {
            // ...
            $this->validate($request, [
               'nombre' => 'min:2',
               'direccion' => 'min:2',
               'telefono' => 'min:2'
            ]);
            // ...
        }

        // ...
   }
   ```
2. El segundo método que plantea la documentación para generar la redirección automática, en este caso sin usar el trait, es llamar el método validate en una instancia del validador:

   ```
   public function crearEstudiantes(Request $request)
   {

       Validator::make($request->all(), [
           'nombre' => 'min:2',
           'direccion' => 'min:2',
           'telefono' => 'min:2'
       ])->validate();

       // ...

   }
   ```

Más información en la documentación oficial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Comment: Bueno, antes de plantear esta pregunta ya habia visto esas dos opciones en la documentacion, pero no acaban de convencerme, ya que la logica en algunos de mis metodos es bastante amplia y por eso queria reducir un poco el codigo de los metodos implementando las validaciones,. Creo que tambien se podria hacer una validacion conjunta con el excepction handler de laravel, pero aun lo estoy aprendiendo. De momento creo que la segunda opcion que me planteas es la que usaré ya que me permite conseguir poner la validacione en un metodo aparte que es lo que queria. Muy agradecido por tu respuesta.